# ActiveRecord check existence of multiple records in a single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
def joined
  contacts = params[:contacts] || []

  contacts.keep_if do |contact|
    User.exists?(phone: contact)
  end

  render :json => {contacts: contacts}
end
```

I am trying subset an array of contacts based on the condition if there is an user with the specified contact in database. The problem with the above code is that I hit the database for every contact in the array. Is there way to do this in one shot with ActiveRecord?

Edit1: Fixed typo,
Edit2: Better explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that from a list of numbers you want to select only those where a `user.phone` is in numbers list:

```
params[:contacts]  = ['2345435', '5675678', '898785']

def joined
  numbers = params[:contacts] || []
  contacts = User.where(phone: numbers).pluck(:phone)
  render :json => {contacts: contacts}
end
```

this will return only contacts(phone numbers) of the users found in db by phone number.

example with emails (in your case would be phones):

```
1.8 :002 > emails = ['admin2002@gmail.com', 'admin2002@yahoo.com', 'admin2002@hotmail.com']
1.8 :007 > contacts = User.where(:email => emails).pluck(:email)
   (1.3ms)  SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`is_company` = 0 AND `users` .`email` IN ('admin2002@gmail.com', 'admin2002@yahoo.com', 'admin2002@hotmail.com')
 => ["admin2002@gmail.com", "admin2002@yahoo.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def joined
  contacts = params[:contacts] || []

  db_contacts = User.where(:phone=> contacts.map(&:contact)).select(:phone) #=> returns all the existing users phone num

  # This is not required if your intention is only to have contacts that exists in db
  contacts.keep_if{ |contact| db_contacts.include?(contact) }

  render :json => {contacts: db_contacts}
end
```